# instantiating a struct in a function call as an argument

Tags: c, struct

In [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8030258) comment on Hacker News, this syntax was mentioned:

```
 func((struct somestruct){.x = 0, .y = 1});
```

Could anybody tell me what this is called and then give a complete example of the function declaration that would allow this? (Not this exact function call, just a complete demonstration of this concept.) Or point me to some resources where I can learn more about this. Thanks!

EDIT: Feel free to comment why you down-voted.

Comment: @Zaibis, I was looking for an example of the function declaration and what this is called. I didn't realize it was such a stupid question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *compound literal*. This creates an instance of `struct somestruct` that dies at the end of the function call expression, and passes it to func.

The signature of the function is simply :

```
[whatever] func(struct somestruct arg);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Could anybody tell me what this is called

The `(){}` operator is called the compound literal operator and initializing structure members using their name is called the designated initializer feature. Both compound literals and designated initializers are features introduced in c99.

Compound literals are described in 6.5.2.5 in c99 and designated initializers in 6.7.8.